# Visual Studio Webform Debugging - Page Never Loads

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I have a project that consists of two web forms. When I try to debug (run the program) in visual studio 2010 the page loads forever. It was edited by someone else a long time ago and it worked before they changed the web forms. It works when it is live on the actual website but locally on the computer it won't run. Has anyone ever had this problem before or know what could be causing this to happen? I'm assuming it is some sort of back end c# code or the html code that is causing the problem because other projects I have made of web forms successfully run locally on my computer.